# Is this Approach correct? Determine number of dice rolls required to obtain the 3rd five

Tags: probability, statistics

If we roll a pair of dice repeatedly, how many rolls do we need to obtain the nth five (example 3rd five)?

I think this can be modeled using a negative binomial distribution. Is this naive?

If we want to calculate the Pr(N>5) where N is the number of rolls required, can I approach it as 1-Pr(N<=4)?
- If so, does that mean I calculate
    $\sum\limits_{i=0}^4 (negativeBin(i,p))$ ?

Comment: Do you want the number to be 5 specifically or equal or grater than 5?

Comment: I want Pr(N>5).  So isn't that $1-Pr(N<=4)$?  I guess what I don't understand is whether Pr(N<=4) is the sum of all the Pr from 0...4

Comment: I said that because in the title of the problem you seem to seek the nth 5, not 5 or 6

Comment: For $\Pr(N\gt 5)$ we want $1-\Pr(N\le 5)$.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. So to find 1- pr(n<=5) do I do  $\sum\limits_{i=0}^5 (negativeBin(i,p))$ ? or just $1 - (negativeBin(5,p))$?

Comment: Say $N$ is the time until the third five. Then $\Pr(N=i)=\binom{i-1}{2}(1/6)^3(5/6)^{i-3}$. Sum from $i=3$ to $i=5$. Subtract the result from $1$.

Comment: Am I misunderstanding the question somehow?  "How many rolls are required to obtain a third $5$?"  Given any finite length of time it is *possible* that you don't roll a single 5 in that time, just like it is *possible* that you flip a billion heads in a row on a fair coin.  Is there an invisible "number of rolls to roll a third 5 **with 95% certainity**" that I'm not seeing?  Or an "**on average**, how many rolls do you need to roll a third 5?"

Comment: The probability that the third $5$ occurs on the $i$-th roll is given in the comment above, which had to be edited a couple of times since I did not see the TeX. The average number of rolls happens to be $18$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help. I was just having trouble breaking down the sum here and making sure the negativeBinomial was the appropriate pmf for this problem. If you make it the answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we perform an experiment independently until the $k$-th success, where the probability of success on any trial is $p$. Let $N$ be the number of trials we use.

Then $N$ has negative binomial distribution with parameters $k$ and $p$. Let us find the probability that $N=n$.

We have $N=n$ if we have $k-1$ successes in the first $n-1$ trials, and success on the $n$-th trial. Thus
$$\Pr(N=n)=\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}p=\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}.\tag{1}$$

Suppose for example that $k=3$ and we want $\Pr(N\gt 5)$. We have $N\gt 5$ precisely if it is not the case that $N\le 5$. Thus $N\gt 5$ has probability
$$1-(\Pr(N=3)+\Pr(N=4)+\Pr(N=5)).$$
For the above probabilities, use Formula (1), with $p=1/6$.

**Remark:** The negative binomial $N$ with parameters $k$ and $N$ is the sum of $k$ (independent) geometric random variables with parameter $p$. Thus $E(N)=\frac{k}{p}$.

Answer (score 1):

To have Bernoulii success number $n$ on the roll number $k$, you need $n-1$ successes and $k-n$ failures in any order, then one more success, at success probability $1/6$.

$$\mathsf P(X_n=k) = \binom{k-1}{n-1} \frac{5^{k-n}}{6^k}$$

Now find the expectation of this $$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X_n) & =\sum_{k=n}^\infty k\binom{k-1}{n-1}\frac{5^{k-n}}{6^k}
\\[1ex] & = 6 n
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively.  As it is a Geometrically Distributed, we expect the *first success* on roll $6$.  After obtaining the first success, we then expect the second success on the $6$ roll *after* the first one, and so on.

Then, because of linearity of expectation, we expect success $n$ on roll $6n$.